# UITableViewRowAction not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I have an `UITableView` that I manage in a controller with `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. In this table I have a custom cell, the problem is that the function `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` gets called only sometimes (maybe when I swype in a particular way, I don't know),  my code is the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let doneAction: UITableViewRowAction
    //let highlightAction: UITableViewRowAction
    if(self.compiti[indexPath.row].completato){
        doneAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Da Fare") { (UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            let compito = self.compiti[indexPath.row]
            self.db.contrassegnaCompito(compito)
            UITableViewRowAction
       }
        doneAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }else{
        doneAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Fatto") { (UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            let compito = self.compiti[indexPath.row]
            self.db.contrassegnaCompito(compito)
        }
        doneAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 67/255, green: 160/255, blue: 71/255, alpha: 0.7)
    }
    return [doneAction]
}
```

Comment: what do you mean, **maybe when i swype in a particular way, I don't know?**

Comment: Is your tableView inside a scrollView?

Comment: @KumarKL that sometimes it works... but i don't know why. If i try 10 swypes 1 will work

Comment: @SamM No, it isn't

Comment: Did you try on a real device ? Problem persists?

Comment: Yes, it does the same. @MatGrlt

Answer (score 3):

you need to add this method implementation as well or you won't be able to swipe to display the actions

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // it can be empty
}
```

Comment: Its works for me. (Based on the version we need to use this)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this code, try starting from this and you will probably find when the problem occurs

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    var doneAction :UITableViewRowAction!

    doneAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Da Fare") { (UITableViewRowAction, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            UITableViewRowAction
    }
    return [doneAction]
}
```

Comment: Still no action, i think that there is something else maybe in my cell that is "capturing" the action...